# Is there a WPF control which will show a list of files in an Explorer-like view?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I often need to display a list of files to the user, say, as a result of a search query.

Typically I describe my own simple DataTemplate for `FileInfo`. But I'm lazy to re-implement all the Explorer's functionality: the Views, Sorting, Context Menus and drag&drop.

I feel like the problem is common and someone has already assembled a good library for this purpose.

Comment: I just had a look on LogicNP's FileView control, but it doesn't seem to allow specifying a custom list of files.

Comment: From LogicNP's site: "Supports Custom Items (eg : database records) in addition to standard shell items (files, folders, UNC locations, printers, etc)". But I haven't downloaded it to look

Comment: Body of reply to my support request: "Thank you for taking the time to evaluate our products.

FileView cannot show items from multiple folders at once. You can use the AddCustomItem for this, but you will have to specify the displayname, icon, etc yourself."

Comment: Does it have to be free?

Comment: this link maybe interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382861/explorer-theme-for-wpf-listview

Comment: @Jon: preferably, but not necessarily

Comment: @modosansreves If you display files after search, it won't be difficult to set icon and name. Also it is possible to write derived class with properties such as ItemsSource and ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked Windows API CodePack it had some WPF sample with explore functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You may look over controls in [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm): this [FolderView](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/E544A5BA-49EF-469D-B926-6DF9E55D9D64/) control and this [FileView](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0850E431-344D-4464-96A4-695D9A93E4A6/) control.

Or look over this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFFileExplorer.aspx) and control.

Comment: LogicNP's FileView doesn't provide handy way to work with custom list of files. As a workaround for that one may add elements to the control *and* implement right click and drag&drop again.

Comment: The closest component provided by Actipro is DataGrid. Or ... am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about Actipro. I edit my answer, may connrol in this article help you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Api Code Pack comes with a user control (ExplorerBrowser) which you can use directly in your application.

Comment: ExplorerBrowser is great. How do I specify list of files (or ShellItems)? There is a Navigate() method, but I need to display results from a custom search.

Comment: @modosansreves: I haven't used the control myself so I can't help with that. Please post your findings once you figure it out as I believe it will be interesting for others too