# Explorer theme for WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, explorer

How do I get the explorer theme in a WPF ListView?
I know that one answer is the GridView, but that is like the *Details* view in Windows Explorer.
I need the **List, Tiles and Icons** view themed like the Explorer.
How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) has an Explorer browser control, which has exactly the same appearance as the Windows Explorer (of course I'm assuming you want to display files, not something else...)

Anyway, if you want to do it yourself, you could create several custom views in addition to the `GridView`. This way you could just change the `View` property of the `ListView` to switch between list, tiles, icons and details. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx) for details on how to create a custom view.

Comment: The Windows API Code Pack won't help you then, but the second approach I suggested is probably your best option