# How to add property to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

VB6 had a `fileListBox` with `.path` property and I am trying to add that property to regular listbox.

```
ListBox myfilelistbox = new ListBox();
```

and the one generated with `XAML`.

Comment: How are you trying to add? And http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: @Yahya at the moment I am using global variables but that seems very wrong

Comment: Edit your question and post some sample code

Comment: There is no `FileListBox` in C#. You'd have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ListBox is a generic control which displays list of items in a linear manner. What you wish to do is to display a hierarchy of items, not a list of them.

There are no such built in controls and you will have to build one for yourself or find some that others have implemented.

Check more information on this other Stack Overflow thread [Is there a WPF control which will show a list of files in an Explorer-like view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225466/is-there-a-wpf-control-which-will-show-a-list-of-files-in-an-explorer-like-view).

The following article on CodeProject could help you: [A WPF File ListView and ComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167873/A-WPF-File-ListView-and-ComboBox)

Comment: no no, that control was just a listbox which had property .path and used getFiles to populate regular listbox. I know how to populate it, I would just need to add that property for easier use throughout the code.

Comment: You cannot add extra properties on the existing class. You can create your own class and inherit ListBox and add Path property to that class. Will that work for you?

Comment: That seems like a good way